# Where exactly does the edit_{taxonomy} hook fire?

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm at my wits end. I'm beginning a project that may involve using an action hook in WP that is not well-documented: edit_{$taxonomy}

I'm trying to determine exactly when this hook runs, so I just wrote a basic function with an echo for testing. Then, I added it to functions.php in a child theme. Invariably, the line with the echo causes a "Headers already sent" error. If I comment out the echo, it's fine. I thought it might have something to do with the order in which php files are loaded when using child themes, so I went head and pasted it into the bottom of the parent theme functions.php. Same issue.

Here's the code:

```
add_action('edit_expedited-status', 'category_status_email');
function category_status_email() {
echo "Testing";
}
```

Any thoughts or ideas appreciated.

#### Update

*Note: Update not from author*

On /wp-includes/taxonomy.php, you'll find (v3.3) on line 1586 the following filter under the context/action `edit`:

```
$value = apply_filters("edit_{$taxonomy}_{$field}", $value, $term_id);
```

Comment: I can't find any action named `'edit_{WHATEVER}-status'` in core. Could you please point at the file + file number?

Comment: It's not listed in the Codex. It is listed on Adam Brown's hook directory: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_%7B$taxonomy%7D.

Comment: Just to be clear, the custom taxonomy I'm using has an id of "expedited-status" that's why the hook is "edit_expedited-status". It's a variable hook.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why someone changed the title of the post. While I am, ultimately, trying to determine the role of this hook, this post is specifically about the strange header error I'm getting. I reverted.

Comment: WordPress is probably trying to send headers after you echo. If you `echo "Testing";die();` you won't get that error. I'm a little unclear about what your question is -- do you want to know when `edit_$taxonomy` runs?

Comment: Please don't rely on automated sources. They're buggy by default. Do a cross-file search in core before you try to use them or use the provided links on Adam Browns site to proof that this filter exists. The action you named **does not exist**. There're some similar named _filters_, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Please have a read on how to work with filters and actions (I'm not repeating it here).</sup>

#### The filter in a theme or plugin

```
// inside /wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1586
$value = apply_filters("edit_{$taxonomy}_{$field}", $value, $term_id);

// inside some theme file that runs before - best on functions.php during your themes bootstrap:
function wpse40709_edit_tax_field( $value, $term_id )
{
    // Do modifications

    return $value;
}
// Should be hooked in bootstrap, so best would be 'after_setup_theme' until 'admin_init'
add_filter( 'edit_YOUR-TAXONOMY-NAME_YOUR-FIELD-NAME', 'wpse40709_edit_tax_field', 20, 2 );
```

#### The filter in core

The filter gets triggered, when

```
sanitize_term_field($field, $value, $term_id, $taxonomy, $context)
```

runs. So the `$field` is whatever name your field has.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to run the hook during init

Comment: Please, elaborate the Answer a bit more... Code example?

Comment: Please [improve your answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Explain _why_ your suggestion solves the issue.